# Best way to host micro services while choosing between Azure Web App for Containers using ASE Vs Docker CE on IaaS VMs RHEL

Tags: azure-web-app-service, docker-container, azure-container-service

My applications/services are written in NodeJS using Loopback framework & use wide variety of Node Modules span from usual to libraries which generate PDFs etc.,

I already have running 'XYZ' application in Docker CE Containers on RHEL VM as set of microservices inter-connected & connectecd with different services, DB & other system using VNET. Now separately there are few other independent external 'ABC' services which are hosted through Web App as Container using ASE & Linux Service Plan. The internal debate is why not to host all applications using ASE through Web Apps. I can think of degree of control which i get in VM Vs PaaS, but not able to clearly articulate that control & other arguments in support of VM for now.

I am aware of AKS, ACS & Service Fabric, but these are out of question as of now as in environment we are in, today it is not allowed.

Need guidance on deciding best way to host micro services out of two from question asked.

Comment: No much experience, but as I know, you cannot control the service plan which your application host when you use the Azure Web app. IaaS VM with Docker installed, you can control all of it. It's just my knowledge.

Comment: @CharlesXu your assertion is right, but I need more convincing & thoughtful or researched answer.